# devIL .so on ubuntu where do I put them - run time error

Tags: c++, linux, devil

I am currently porting my game from windows to Linux. Debian(home) and Fedora(uni). It builds fine however at run time is expecting  `error while loading shared libraries: libIL.so.1`.

Firstly what is the .1 all about? I tried use placeing libIL.so and .1 next to the executable but that still had the same error. What do I do? - Bare in mind that I do not have root access on the Fedora machine.

Comment: Google for LD_PRELOAD...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `libIL.so` into the same directory as your executable `mygame`, then create a start-up script for your game, say `mygame.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
LD_PRELOAD=. ./mygame
```

Now you can start your game from the command line using `./mygame.sh`.

---

edit: What I actually meant above was `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `LD_PRELOAD`. Put all your libraries together with your executable and use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.` , then the library loader will look in the current folder for all libraries it needs.

Comment: How do I do multiple preloads?

Comment: see my edit. With `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` you don't need "multiple" things, just all libraries in the current directory.